# Bootstrap 3 modal not loading YouTube videos

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3 and it's modal, I'm trying to load YouTube videos via the rel attribute and jQuery. I've got it to work previously on Bootstrap 2.3.2 modals, however with BS3 I'm unable too. I get the modal window to show, but nothing loads.

```
HTML:

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade yt-link" rel="kfVsfOSbJY0">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h1 class="h3">It's Friday!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

JS:

$('.yt-link').on('show', function () {
    $(this).html('<iframe width="533" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).attr('rel') + '?rel=0;showinfo=0;autohide=1;controls=2;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});

$('.yt-link').on('hide', function () {
    $(this).html('&nbsp;');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ref:**

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals  (see Events)

```
$('.yt-link').on('show', function () {
```

works on TB 2. They changed this in TB3

```
$('.yt-link').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
```

and hide is

```
$('.yt-link').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
```